# WinUI 3: Saving A File; "Specified cast not valid"

Tags: c#, winui-3, savefiledialog

I have successfully did this in an app that had nothing but a rich edit box and a menu with a save button.

I am now trying to add it to my other project that has multiple pages. The menu is on page two of the app, and it is no longer working.

Here's my code:

```
private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();

    var hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);

    InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(savePicker, hWnd);

    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt", ".rtf" });
    var enteredFileName = "My Document";
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = enteredFileName;

    StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream randAccStream =
            await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        ScratchPad.Document.SaveToStream((TextGetOptions)Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, randAccStream);
    }
}
```

The exception happens at:

```
var hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
```

I have tried a few different things such as referencing the main window and nothing has fixed it.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/7951

Comment: @codo that makes me feel much better knowing it isn't just me having the issue. I'm doing this based on what was in the WinUi 3 Library and got very confused that it doesn't work. If nothing else, it gave me a lot of relief, and I now know not to use WindowNative

Comment: The solution seems to be to use `WindowNative.GetWindowHandle()` but instead of passing `this` passing the top window, e.g. `App.Window`.

Comment: @Codo What I did that fixed it was I instantiated a new window. I don't have enough reputation points to make my solution as the correct fix, but I posted an answer to my post with the code that did the trick. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how to fix the problem I am having. It's almost embarrassingly simple:

```
private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
    //-----
    Window win = new();
    //-----
    var hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(win);

    InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(savePicker, hWnd);

    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt", ".rtf" });
    var enteredFileName = "My Document";
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = enteredFileName;

    StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream randAccStream =
            await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        ScratchPad.Document.SaveToStream((TextGetOptions)Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, randAccStream);
    }
}
```

A new window must be instantiated so:

```
Window win = new();
```

Then "win" can be passed as a parameter rather than "this":

```
var hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(win);
```

Comment: Posted an answer without instantiating a new `Window`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `Window` instead of a `Page`.

Usually, you make the `MainWindow` accessible:

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Window Window { get; } = new MainWindow();

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Window.Activate();
    }
}
```

Then in your page:

```cs
var hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(App.Window);
```

Comment: That’s what ChatGPT says to do. It throws exceptions. I appreciate your help. I can’t mark my own answer as the solution or anything because I don’t have enough reputation or whatever. Instantiating a new window fixed it, and now it’s working perfectly.

Comment: I can't tell what could go wrong by instantiating a `Window` just for the `FileSavePicker` but I'm pretty sure it's not the way you are supposed to do so. I actually created a sample app for this answer. It should work. Can you post more code around how you implemented my answer and accessed the `MainWindow`? You shouldn't get exceptions.